# How do I create a worksheet from a stored worksheet variable

Tags: excel, worksheet, vba

new VBA user here...

I don't know how to create a worksheet from a variable stored in memory.  What I'm trying to do is create multiple copies of an existing "template" sheet from the open workbook, manipulate them in memory (e.g. change range values, add formulas, etc.) and then create them in the open workbook as actual sheets.

I can create the copies in memory and store them in an array, but I cannot then create the actual worksheet in my workbook.  Help please :)

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wsTemplate As Worksheet
Dim wsCopies(1 To 5) As Worksheet
Dim x As Long

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Worksheet Test")
Set wsCopy = ws


For x = 1 To 5
    Set wsCopies(x) = wsTemplate
'used this line to make sure this actually copied into memory
    Debug.Print wsCopies(x).Range("A1").FormulaR1C1
Next x
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Set wsCopies(x) = wsTemplate` You didn't initialize `wstemplate`?

Comment: Sorry findwindow, I actually did initialize but I made the code generic for this question and did it quickly.  Thanks for the replies guys. I find it hard to believe that there's no way to do this.. Is it something a class module could handle instead?  What's the point of holding a worksheet variable in memory if you can't manipulate it and spit it back out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There really isn't a "Worksheet in memory" that only exists in memory. You create a new worksheet, and there it is, in your workbook. There's also not a great way to duplicate a worksheet without a little trickery. Something like:

```
For x = 1 To 5
    wsTemplate.copy after:=wsTemplate
    Set wsCopies(x) = wb.Sheets(wsTemplate.index + 1)
'used this line to make sure this actually copied into memory
    Debug.Print wsCopies(x).Range("A1").FormulaR1C1
Next x
```

Which isn't terrible, but it's not exactly what you were thinking. If you aren't into `application.screenupdating = false` and all that, you could set the `wsCopies(x).visible` to `xlSheetHidden` and do your further manipulation until you toggle to visible again.

Comment: Thanks JNevill. I was trying to avoid it because I thought it would be much cleaner my way rather than trying to manage the order of the sheets after being pasted into the workbook. I think that may be the only way.

Comment: I believe there is a worksheets.add method that would be closer to what you are thinking, but then you won't have a copy... so this is probably the best way to pull off what you need.